# How can I open a Youtube page with a custom search?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, bots

I'm developing a chatbot, if I write "open Youtube and search red mice" the bot opens the "red mice" Youtube search page with Firefox/Chrome. I've already written the code to open Youtube, but How can I have a custom search from C#?

Comment: You need to observe the url which is generated when you search directly on YouTube site. And try to create the same url in your code and then browse. Example `https://m.youtube.com/results?q=chu%20chu%20tv&sm=1` when I search `chu chu tv` on YouTube website.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite easy. Take a look at YouTube URL after seraching phrase `test search`: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test+search. Only what you need is to build valid URL where in `search_query` parameter you will provide what are you looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember about valid URL encoding. There must be some character changed, for exampe instead of space you have to use `+`.